# changes doesn't take effect on JSON file on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, heroku

i deployed an app to heroku which has a fucntion that counts clicks of elements and add it to JSON file

my main.js is like this

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = fs.readFileSync('count.json');
var Words = JSON.parse(file);

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log('we are listeining'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json({ limit : '1mb' })); 

app.get('/add/:word', addWord);

function addWord(request, response) {
  var data = request.params;
  var word = data.word;
  var reply;
  var found = false;
  for (i = 0; i < Words.length; i++){
    if (Words[i].type == word){
      Words[i].count++;
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }

if (!found) {
  Words.push({"type": word , "count": 1});
}

  var x = JSON.stringify(Words, null, 2);
  fs.writeFile('count.json', x, finished);

  function finished(){
    console.log('Yay')
  }
    /* 
    console.log(Words[word]); */

/*     response.send(reply); */
  }
```

and the script file is like this

```
all.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  elemid = e.target.id;
  elemclass = e.target.className;
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = elemid + "_overlay";
  div.className = "overlay";
  document.body.appendChild(div);
    div.style.display = "block";
    fetch(elemid+'.txt')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then((data) => {
   div.innerHTML = data; 
  }).then(fetch("/add/"+elemid)
  .then(response => {
   return response.json();
    }).then(function(data){
      console.log(data[0].count);
  })
  .then(fetch('js/cases.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) =>{
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      if (elemid == data[i].case){
      let a = document.createElement('a');
      a.id = data[i].id;
      a.innerText = data[i].case
    div.appendChild(a);
      }
    }
    console.log(data[0].id);
  })
  )
  )
 }, false)
})
```

locally it writes the JSON of of count perfectly but when deployed it on heroku changes doesn't take effect and there is no error appears in the console.

Comment: Have you confirmed it isn't a browser caching issue? Have you tried writing to heroku logs and checking them?

Comment: heroku log "yay!" which i console logging it after adding the word,  but after it gives request time out to the get method ```2020-05-10T01:17:44.729622+00:00 app[web.1]: Yay
2020-05-10T01:18:04.986972+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/add/voiceOverlapping" host=bss-ticketmaker.herokuapp.com request_id=bb2eaf27-bb8a-435c-8585-30d1486e1c78 fwd="156.205.74.140" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https ```

Comment: Can anyone give me a hint